# React Native Xcode build error on react-native-linear-gradient (-lBVLinearGradient)

Tags: react-native

I have followed all installation process according to the github page for react-native-linear-gradient.

But when I try to compile for ios (both through `react-native run-ios` command and Xcode), I get the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lBVLinearGradient
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've already opened the project through xcworkspace in which most suggests so when using Cocoapods, but the error persists anyhow.

Any clue on this?

Comment: What is your `react-native` version?

Comment: `"react-native": "0.61.1",` is the version from package.json

Comment: I am also facing the same error. @NewbieCoder Did you have any solution for this error

Comment: Turns out it wasn't directly linked to the said library. It was some library else that was causing it to not compile properly. In my case, I was using ksyvideo plugin in which cannot be compiled in Xcode. Removing the library was the solution.

Comment: @NewbieCoder I have also this problem. Could you find some solution?

Comment: @TuranZamanlı please refer to my comment on Jan 13th. It was specific to my case, though.

Comment: @NewbieCoder I just changed build to new build system. It works

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70466140/551744

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem after upgrading 0.62.1 and the following did the trick for me:

1. Switched my project to new build system (was using legacy)
2. Manually deleted the .xcworkspace in ios folder
3. Removed app from simulator (also deleted all derived data) see [how](https://guides.codepath.com/ios/Fixing-Xcode)
4. `rm -rf node_modules && sudo yarn install`
5. `cd ios && pod deintegrate`
6. `pod install`
7. Run project in xcode

This worked for me, hope it can help someone