# React-Native error ld: library not found for -lBVLinearGradient

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Installed 'react-native-lienar-gradient' library in my new react-native project.

Added pod 'BVLinearGradient', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient' in Podfile

Performed pod install in ios directory

Xcode build gives the following error:

**ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L-L/Users/pavneet/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Krowym-fttolxdorzfwjbcgjwmxijsnufkv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BVLinearGradient'
ld: library not found for -lBVLinearGradient
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

[Error in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96Mih.png)

Tried deleting Podfile.lock, cleaning xcode build, manually linking library by react-native link command, deleting Derived data folder

Also tried by adding libBVLinearGradient.a on Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries

Environment

react-native:0.63.2

react-native-linear-gradient:2.5.6

Answer (score 6):

Can you try this.

First deintegrate and install the pods again

1. `sudo gem update –system`
2. `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`
3. `pod setup`
4. `cd ios`
5. `pod deintegrate`
6. `pod install`

And then go back and run the app by `deleting ios build and watchman` and `clearing metro server and simulator cache` and also `deleting and reinstalling node modules`

7. `cd ..`
8. ```
   watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*  && rm -fr $TMPDIR/metro-cache* && rm -fr $TMPDIR/haste-map-metro*  &&  rm -rf ios/build && xcrun simctl erase all && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache verify && npm install && react-native run-ios -- --reset-cache
   ```

Answer (score 2):

The version in pod file was `platform :ios, '11.0'`, but the deployment version was `9.0`. Changed to `11.0` and the app could be achieved!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1-add this in pod file:
pod 'BVLinearGradient', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient'

2-npx pod-install

Answer (score 0):

I know this is so late, I hope you've already solved your problem. However, this solution might help someone else.

1. Quit Xcode.
2. `users/${username}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` go this directory and clean your project data. (Make sure hidden files are visible to see `Library` file under `users/${username}`. `Command+Shift+.` combination switches hidden files visibility.)
3. Open your terminal, change the current working directory to your local project directory/ios.
4. `pod deintegrate` and `pod install` again.
5. Open your project .xcworkspace file in Xcode.
6. Click on your project name on the left navigation bar and click your project name under PROJECT.
7. Type `Library Search Paths` and search.
8. Click twice on the path which is beside `Library Search Paths` and delete the first and the last quote characters.([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMYWL.png) It should look like this.)
9. Lastly press `Command+B` to build your project.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this solution. So I tried a lot of different. But didn't. Only this  solution is worked for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70581543/8144872