# Xcode - library not found for -lBVLinearGradient

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, clang

I've moved to Macbook Pro M1, and my Xcode version is 12.5.1

When running my app, I'm getting below error:

```
ld: library not found for -lBVLinearGradient
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm also using `react-native-linear-gradient` (version 2.5.6) library, for which this error is related to.

Comment: Can you post the react native error stack?

Comment: @MichaelBahl I'm only getting this error on Xcode, because I'm running app from Xcode only. Or I hope I understood your question correctly

Comment: What happen when you run the app with `react-native run ios`

Comment: @MichaelBahl i get this error - Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Comment: Pro tip: when showing text-based errors, please show them as text, not images. This makes it easier for Stack Overflow to work with search engine crawlers, readers' search engines, and readers' screen readers.

Comment: Please also refrain from saying how long you have been stuck on a problem - it is not relevant to getting help. Remember that your posts form long-term Q&A, and that Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70466140/551744

Answer (score 1):

When I did the following steps, I was able to build without any errors

## 1. Paste these lines at the bottom of the pod file

```
post_install do |installer|
  find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/React/CxxBridge/RCTCxxBridge.mm",
 "_initializeModules:(NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)modules", "_initializeModules:(NSArray<Class> *)modules")
 find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/turbomodule/core/platform/ios/RCTTurboModuleManager.mm",
 "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(strongModule))", "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(Class(strongModule)))")

 installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
  config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
 end
end

def find_and_replace(dir, findstr, replacestr)
 Dir[dir].each do |name|
     text = File.read(name)
     replace = text.gsub(findstr,replacestr)
     if text != replace
         puts "Fix: " + name
         File.open(name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
         STDOUT.flush
     end
 end
 Dir[dir + '*/'].each(&method(:find_and_replace))
end
```

## 2. You have to exclude arm64 for simulator architecture both from your main project and the Pod project

Main Project
[image]

Pod Project
[image]

## 3. Delete DerivedData

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```

## 4. Rebuild node_modules and pod install

```
rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf ios/Podfile.lock && rm -rf package-lock.json && rm -rf yarn.lock
yarn
cd ios/ && pod install && cd ..
```

If there is nothing I forgot, everything was working when I did all these. It took me a long time to put these pieces together but it turned out nice

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this issue with amend my Podfile by adding this:

```
post_install do |installer|
  ## Fix for XCode 12.5
  find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/React/CxxBridge/RCTCxxBridge.mm",
 "_initializeModules:(NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)modules", "_initializeModules:(NSArray<Class> *)modules")
 find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/turbomodule/core/platform/ios/RCTTurboModuleManager.mm",
 "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(module))", "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(Class(module)))")
end

def find_and_replace(dir, findstr, replacestr)
  Dir[dir].each do |name|
      text = File.read(name)
      replace = text.gsub(findstr,replacestr)
      if text != replace
          puts "Fix: " + name
          File.open(name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
          STDOUT.flush
      end
  end
  Dir[dir + '*/'].each(&method(:find_and_replace))
end
```